# Modify surface code to solve for 4 dimensions instead of 3 [edited]

Tags: python, scipy, surface, geometry-surface

I found this great question with some concise code that, with a couple of tweaks, fits a 3D polynomial surface onto a set of points of in space.

[Python 3D polynomial surface fit, order dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997152/python-3d-polynomial-surface-fit-order-dependent)

My version is below.

Ultimately, I've realized that I need to fit a surface over time, i.e. I need to solve for a 4 dimensional surface, and I've struggled with it.

I came up with a very hacky and computationally intensive work-around. I create a surface for each time interval. Then I create a grid of points and find the Z value for each point on each surface. So now I have a bunch of x,y points and each one has a list of z values that need to flow smoothly from one interval to the next. So we do a regression on the z values. Now that the z-flow is smooth, I refit a surface for each time interval based on the x,y points and whatever their smoothed Z value is for the relevant time interval.

Its what it sounds like. Clunky and suboptimal. The resulting surfaces flow more smoothly and still perform okay but there's gotta be a way to cut out the middle man and solve for that 4th dimension directly in the *fitSurface* function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import itertools

# Start black magic
def xy_powers(order):
    powers = itertools.product(range(order + 1), range(order + 1))
    return [tup for tup in powers if sum(tup) <= order]

def fitSurface(x, y, z, order):
    ncols = (order + 1)**2
    G = np.zeros((x.size, ncols))
    ij = xy_powers(order)
    for k, (i,j) in enumerate(ij):
        G[:,k] = x**i * y**j
    m, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(G, z, rcond=None)
    return m

def getZValuesForXYInputs(surface, order, x, y):
    order = int(np.sqrt(len(surface))) - 1
    ij = xy_powers(order)
    z = np.zeros_like(x)
    for a, (i,j) in zip(surface, ij):
        z += a * x**i * y**j
    return z
# End black magic

def showRender_3D(x_raw, y_raw, z_raw, xx, yy, zz):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)
    ax.scatter(x_raw, y_raw, z_raw, color='red', zorder=0)
    ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, zorder=10, alpha=0.4)
    ax.set_xlabel('X data')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y data')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z data')
    plt.show()



def main(order):
    # Make generic data
    numdata = 100
    x = np.random.random(numdata)
    y = np.random.random(numdata)
    z = x**2 + y**2 + 3*x**3 + y + np.random.random(numdata)
    t = np.random.randint(1, 4, numdata) # Break the data into 

    # Fit the surface
    m = fitSurface(x, y, z, order)

    # Sample the surface at regular points so we can more easily plot the surface
    nx, ny = 40, 40
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), nx), 
                         np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), ny))
    zz = getZValuesForXYInputs(m, order, xx, yy)

    # Plot it
    showRender_3D(x, y, z, xx, yy, zz)

orderForSurfaceFit = 3
main(orderForSurfaceFit)
```

[image: Example of a surface fit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I think I got this dialed in. I wont go over the how, other than to say that once you study the code enough the black magic doesn't go away but patterns do emerge. I just extended those patterns and it looks like it works.

End result
[image]

<s>Admittedly this is so low res that it look like its not changing from C=1 to C=2 but it is. Load it up and you'll see.</s> The gif should show the flow more cleary now.

---

First the methodology behind the proof. I found a funky surface equation and added a third input variable C (in-effect creating a 4D surface), then studied the surface shape with fixed C values using the original 3D fitter/renderer as a point of trusted reference.

When C is 1, you get a half pipe from hell. A slightly lopsided downsloping halfpipe.
[image: Ortho 1]
[image: Front 1]

Whence C is 2, you get much the same but the lopsidedness is even more exaggerated.
[image: Ortho 2]
[image: Front 2]

When C is 3, you get a very different shape. Like the exaggerated half pipe from above was cut in half, reversed, and glued back together.
[image: Ortho 3]
[image: Front 3]
[image: Side 3]

---

When you run the below code, you get a 3D render with a slider that allows you to flow through the C values from 1 to 3. The values at 1, 2, and 3 look like solid matches to the references. I also added a randomizer to the data to see how it would perform at approximating a surface from imperfect noisy data and I like what I see there too.

Props to the below questions for their code and ideas.

[Python 3D polynomial surface fit, order dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997152/python-3d-polynomial-surface-fit-order-dependent)

[python visualize 4d data with surface plot and slider for 4th variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620661/python-visualize-4d-data-with-surface-plot-and-slider-for-4th-variable)

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider


class Surface4D:
    def __init__(self, order, a, b, c, z):
        # Setting initial attributes
        self.order = order
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.z = z
        # Setting surface attributes
        self.surface = self._fit_surface()
        self.aa = None
        self.bb = None
        self._sample_surface_grid()
        # Setting graph attributes
        self.surface_render = None
        self.axis_3d = None

    # Start black magic math
    def _abc_powers(self):
        powers = itertools.product(range(self.order + 1), range(self.order + 1), range(self.order + 1))
        return [tup for tup in powers if sum(tup) <= self.order]

    def _fit_surface(self):
        ncols = (self.order + 1)**3
        G = np.zeros((self.a.size, ncols))
        ijk = self._abc_powers()
        for idx, (i,j,k) in enumerate(ijk):
            G[:,idx] = self.a**i * self.b**j * self.c**k
        m, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(G, self.z, rcond=None)
        return m

    def get_z_values(self, a, b, c):
        ijk = self._abc_powers()
        z = np.zeros_like(a)
        for s, (i,j,k) in zip(self.surface, ijk):
            z += s * a**i * b**j * c**k
        return z
    # End black magic math

    def render_4d_flow(self):
        # Set up the layout of the graph
        fig = plt.figure()
        self.axis_3d = Axes3D(fig, rect=[0.1,0.2,0.8,0.7])
        slider_ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.05])
        self.axis_3d.set_xlabel('X data')
        self.axis_3d.set_ylabel('Y data')
        self.axis_3d.set_zlabel('Z data')

        # Plot the point cloud and initial surface
        self.axis_3d.scatter(self.a, self.b, self.z, color='red', zorder=0)
        zz = self.get_z_values(self.aa, self.bb, 1)
        self.surface_render = self.axis_3d.plot_surface(self.aa, self.bb, zz, zorder=10, alpha=0.4, color="b")

        # Setup the slider behavior
        slider_start_step = self.c.min()
        slider_max_steps = self.c.max()
        slider = Slider(slider_ax, 'time', slider_start_step, slider_max_steps , valinit=slider_start_step)
        slider.on_changed(self._update)

        plt.show()
        input("Once youre done, hit any enter to continue.")

    def _update(self, val):
        self.surface_render.remove()
        zz = self.get_z_values(self.aa, self.bb, val)
        self.surface_render = self.axis_3d.plot_surface(self.aa, self.bb, zz, zorder=10, alpha=0.4, color="b")

    def _sample_surface_grid(self):
        na, nb = 40, 40
        aa, bb = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(self.a.min(), self.a.max(), na), 
                            np.linspace(self.b.min(), self.b.max(), nb))
        self.aa = aa
        self.bb = bb

def noisify_array(one_dim_array, randomness_multiplier):
    listOfNewValues = []
    range = abs(one_dim_array.min()-one_dim_array.max())
    for item in one_dim_array:
        # What percentage are we shifting the point dimension by
        shift = np.random.randint(0, 101)
        shiftPercent = shift/100
        shiftPercent = shiftPercent * randomness_multiplier

        # Is that shift positive or negative
        shiftSignIndex = np.random.randint(0, 2)
        shifSignOption = [-1, 1]
        shiftSign = shifSignOption[shiftSignIndex]

        # Shift it
        newNoisyPosition = item + (range * (shiftPercent * shiftSign))
        listOfNewValues.append(newNoisyPosition)
    return np.array(listOfNewValues)


def generate_data():
    # Define our range for each dimension
    x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 20)
    y = np.linspace(-6, 6, 20)
    w = [1, 2, 3]

    # Populate each dimension
    a,b,c,z = [],[],[],[]
    for X in x:
        for Y in y:
            for W in w:
                a.append(X)
                b.append(Y)
                c.append(W)
                z.append((1 * X ** 4) + (2 * Y ** 3) + (X * Y ** W) + (4 * X) + (5 * Y))

    # Convert them to arrays
    a = np.array(a)
    b = np.array(b)
    c = np.array(c)
    z = np.array(z)

    return [a, b, c, z]

def main(order):
    # Make the data
    a,b,c,z = generate_data()

    # Show the pure data and best fit
    surface_pure_data = Surface4D(order, a, b, c, z)
    surface_pure_data.render_4d_flow()

    # Add some noise to the data
    a = noisify_array(a, 0.10)
    b = noisify_array(b, 0.10)
    c = noisify_array(c, 0.10)
    z = noisify_array(z, 0.10)

    # Show the noisy data and best fit
    surface_noisy_data = Surface4D(order, a, b, c, z)
    surface_noisy_data.render_4d_flow()


# ----------------------------------------------------------------

orderForSurfaceFit = 5
main(orderForSurfaceFit)
```

[Edit 1: I've started to incorporate this code into my real projects and I found some tweaks to make things ore sensible. Also there's a scope problem where the runtime needs to be paused while it's still in the scope of the render_4d_flow function in order for the slider to work.]

[Edit 2: Higher resolution gif that shows the flow from c=2 to c=3]